# How to nest two scrollableview android with titanium

Tags: android, scroll, titanium

I got a little worried because I'd like a nested `scrollableview` but his work was his clammy.
I can has scrolled from right to left and when I'm on my second picture I call'd me on the other scrollview scroll but not so it must be something I did wrong. aillor and how it's done for the second vertical scroll be done?

**scroll principal**

```
 Titanium.include('cover.js');
 var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor:'#333',
    //orientationModes:Titanium.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT
});
//Titanium.UI.orientation = Titanium.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT;

var rotate = Ti.UI.create2DMatrix().rotate(90);
var counterRotate = rotate.rotate(-180);

//create despicture for scroll
var repImage = 'res-long-land-hdpi';
var image = Ti.UI.createImageView({
  image:'android/images/'+repImage+'/default.png'
});

//scroll principal
var scrollView = Titanium.UI.createScrollableView({
    views:[image,cover],//cover call two scroll
    maxZoomScale:1.0,
    currentPage:0,
    showPagingControl:false,
    cacheSize:5,
    zIndex:-100,
});


win.add(scrollView);
win.open();
```

**the second scroll that will go to in the first**

```
cover = Titanium.UI.createView({
    left:0,
    top:0,
});

var repImage = 'res-long-land-hdpi';
var image1 = Ti.UI.createImageView({
  image:'android/images/'+repImage+'/p1.jpg'
});

var image2 = Ti.UI.createImageView({
  image:'android/images/'+repImage+'/p2.jpg'
});

// second scroll
var scrollView1 = Titanium.UI.createScrollableView({
    views:[image1,image2],
    maxZoomScale:1.0,
    currentPage:0,
    showPagingControl:false,
    cacheSize:5,
    zIndex:-100,
    layout:'vertical'
});


cover.add(scrollView1);
```

thank you

Comment: I heard this couldn't be done on Android, curious if it would work or if someone has a solution. +1

Comment: Is there a link in the documentation at all about that @Martin?

Comment: I was told this by someone when I was trying to do it on Android, face to face.  My code wasn't scrolling in the way I wanted.  I found this post where it looks like they may have found a work around just now. http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/114041/scrollview-horizontal-scroll-not-working